# Can you echo PHP code from a variable?

Tags: plugins, php, functions

Ok this is a stupid question, and I'm not sure I even asked it right, but this is what I'm trying to do.

My wordpress theme supports ad placements and I want to use a advertising manager plugin.
I know I can just go through the theme and replace the ad code that's currently there with code from the plugin. However, the theme does some other stuff with ad placement in between posts etc (that I'm not really sure whats involved to preserve). So I'm hoping there is an easier solution.

If I put the php code from the plugin into the ad placement boxes from the theme, all it does is this in the source of the page (basically comments it out).

```
<!--?php if( function_exists( 'pro_ad_display_adzone' ) ) echo pro_ad_display_adzone( 1 ); ?-->
```

This is the code from the theme template file that displays the ad

```
 <?php echo $con_single_ad_post; // ad ?>
```

Any ideas how I could get this to work?

Comment: Are you putting the php into some sort of custom option field or the actual template file? Also can you post what you are actually pasting.

Comment: Yeah, its a field in the theme options. It says you can post HTML (not php obviously). `<?php if( function_exists( 'pro_ad_display_adzone' ) ) echo pro_ad_display_adzone( 1 ); ?>`

Answer (score 1):

Since actual output seems to be done via echoing global variable nothing prevents you to change that variable to something else (between the points where theme creates and echoes it). Like a result of advertisement manager function call.

However I think it would make more sense to stick with one of two functionalities rather than trying to mash them together.